# repost: copy pasting data instead of formula excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

ok i have to repost this  as my original thread was tagged as a duplicate with "the original" thread not having anything to do with my issue and the person who tagged it as a dupe cannot provide the answer.

there's a reason why i'm using activecell in my code as it does something with interaction with outlook and validation of certain conditions from other cells.

```
ActiveCell.Cells(1, 37).Copy Destination:=wsTest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

now i tried :

```
ActiveCell.Cells(1, 37).Copy Destination:=wsTest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).pastespecial
```

but i'm getting error 1004.

if someone will point me here: [how to paste only values in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135560/how-to-paste-only-values-in-excel)

please tell me which  of the 4 answers will actually work, because none of them is working on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the procedure and pass over the value directly.

```
wsTest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ActiveCell.Cells(1, 37).value
```

The `.Value` is the raw underlying value in a cell or the result from a formula if the cell contains a formula. `.Value2` strips the value further where a date like 18-Feb-2015 becomes *42,053*. If you have used number formatting in the cell (e.g. 18-Feb-2015) and wish to retain it, use `.Text` in place of `.Value`.